# Where can I get help with making design decisions for my application?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am working on a [full-stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack) application, and I've got a feature that I want to implement. Now I am not sure how I should design that. For me, it's not trivial and has many things to take into consideration.

The question is more about [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(web_framework)), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), and Websockets. Less UI/UX, and more about performance. Because it is something more complex, I would assume an answer would rather be an opinion.

I've looked at some of the Stack Exchange sites, but I couldn't really find a place to ask the question, and fear being wrong for using them:

- **[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** - Not suitable since the answer would be more of an opinion?
- **[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour)** - Not suitable since the question is more logic/backend related.
- **[Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)** - I don't really have any code to review, it's more theoretical right now and in the planning/design phase.

I would like to know where I can ask such a question.

Comment: I doubt any site will take it as it reads more like a discussion / whiteboard / brainstorm what you need. That said, did you consider to look at the questions at [Software Engineering.se](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Too few software design questions. Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58578/282094)  versus https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic (probably not).